# How to fix "Notice: Undefined variable" error

Tags: php, html, debugging

I am looking at my 'WP_DEBUG' errors and the following two errors/notices pop up in a number of PHP files:

**Notice: Undefined variable: defaultUI in...

Notice: Undefined variable: compileShortcodeUI in...**

I have checked all of the the PHP files and lines specifically and every single one of these refers to this same bit of code:

```
$compileShortcodeUI .= "<div class='whatInsert whatInsert_".$shortcodeName."'>".$defaultUI."</div>";
```

What do I need to change to remove these errors?

Comment: Well either you need to remove that line of code, or make sure the variables used are actually set to some value before it …

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the variable initially.

```
$compileShortcodeUI = ''; // null or any default value
$defaultUI = ''; // null or any default value
$compileShortcodeUI .= "<div class='whatInsert whatInsert_".$shortcodeName."'>".$defaultUI."</div>";
```